# Reading EEPROM entry from sysfs

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, i2c, sysfs, eeprom

I am trying to read an eeprom entry from inside sysfs on beagleboard .Below Entry I am trying to read using simple cat/vi .

```
sys/bus/i2c/drivers/at24/1-0050/eeprom
```

But getting this error : cat: read error: Connection timed out

Can anyone let me know what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

If it is showing connection timed out.. i guess u should check the eeprom if it is connected properly or not or the connecting wires to it are ok..? i do not know on which platform u r using this ,, and how the eeprom is connected to the processor.. if it is through I2C then u need to check if that particular I2C port is enabled or no